# group by fails to keep duplicates

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8.0CE and MySQL server 5.0 on my desktop.
when I use group by the result fails to keep duplicate records, which I need for reference.
How can I deal with this?

for example, I have several dates here in table Scheduler:

```
 sDate:
    10/1/2018
    10/1/2018
    10/2/2018
    10/2/2018
    10/3/2018
    10/3/2018
```

when I do the following statement:

```
SELECT S.sDate
FROM Scheduler S
GROUP BY S.sDate
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

I should get the exact same result in table sDate. However, I am getting this:

```
10/1/2018
10/2/2018
10/3/2018
```

where duplicates are eliminated, which I don't know what to do.

Comment: What is your expected output based on above input data ?

Comment: Your assumption "*I should get exactly same result*" is simply wrong.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I got this one by using inner join. Is there a way to close this question?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you used below query :

```
select S.sDate from Scheduler S group by S.sDate having COUNT(*)>1
```

This query states that you need to display all sDate which have count greater than 1 in the table Scheduler and in your table data all three dates have duplicate entry.

If you want to keep duplicate in your query result then use below query :

```
select S.sDate from Scheduler S group by S.sDate having COUNT(*)>= 1
```

Hope it clears your doubt!

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by a field by definition removes dupliates.

For example, the query

```
SELECT dt, COUNT(*) AS dt_count
FROM Scheduler
GROUP BY dt
```

returns the following results:

```
+------------+----------+
|     dt     | dt_count |
+------------+----------+
| 2018-10-01 |        2 |
| 2018-10-02 |        2 |
| 2018-10-03 |        2 |
+------------+----------+
```

If you had a date that only occurred once, it would still be showed once. For example, if we added a row of `2018-10-04`, we'd have this:

```
+------------+----------+
|     dt     | dt_count |
+------------+----------+
| 2018-10-01 |        2 |
| 2018-10-02 |        2 |
| 2018-10-03 |        2 |
| 2018-10-04 |        1 |
+------------+----------+
```

If you want to keep duplicates, but still figure out which dates occur more than once, you'd need to use a sub-query.

If you have MySQL 8+, which allows CTEs, your query would look like this:

```
WITH 
    Dupes(dt, dt_count) AS
    (
        SELECT dt, COUNT(*)
        FROM Scheduler
        GROUP BY dt
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
SELECT 
    Scheduler.dt,
    Dupes.dt_count
FROM Scheduler
    INNER JOIN Dupes ON
        Dupes.dt = Scheduler.dt
```

With an earlier version that doesn't allow CTEs, you're stuck putting the `Dupes` query inline:

```
SELECT 
    Scheduler.dt,
    Dupes.dt_count
FROM Scheduler
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT dt, COUNT(*) AS dt_count
        FROM Scheduler
        GROUP BY dt
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) Dupes ON
        Dupes.dt = Scheduler.dt
```

Because we're using an `INNER JOIN`, records that don't appear more than once won't show up.